# i am trying to learn django from django documentation but i am getting an error message in the first part of the documentation

Tags: python, django

Using the URLconf defined in blogs.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, polls/, didn’t match any of these.
this is the error i am getting after i wrote the following code:

1. for urls.py

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import include, path

   urlpatterns = [
       path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ]
   ```
2. for polls/urls.py

   ```
   from django.urls import path

   from . import views

   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.index, name='index'),
   ]
   ```

3.for polls/views.py
"""
from django.http import HttpResponse

```
 def index(request):
       return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
"""
```

**how i can i remove this error in vs code**

Comment: Your first code fragment is `blogs/urls.py`?

Comment: Did you restart your Django server after changing the code?

Comment: yes but http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ is not working

Comment: yes i changed the name  of my project from mysite(as mentioned in the django documentation)to blogs

Comment: You can try to add 'polls' to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file

Comment: i tried but it's still not working but my admin page is working

Comment: solved it just had to save the file